# Mouse drag cloning infinite clones

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a mario maker "clone" and I want it to instantiate objects when I hold control and drag. It makes almost infinite tiles. I want it to only make an object if the new position is the same as an old position of an object. Everything snaps to a grid of 1 by 1 blocks

```
public GameObject tilePrefab;

      void OnMouseDrag(){
        Vector2 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
        pos.x = Mathf.Round(pos.x);
        pos.y = Mathf.Round(pos.y);
        transform.position = pos;
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftControl)) {
            if (transform.position != GameObject.Find ("SomePrefabName").transform.position) {
                GameObject myGameObject = Instantiate (tilePrefab) as GameObject;
                myGameObject.name = "SomePrefabName";
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Before Drag]

[image: After Drag]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing to this:

```
public GameObject tilePrefab;
      void OnMouseDrag(){
        Vector2 pos = Input.mousePosition;
        pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos);
        pos.x = Mathf.Round(pos.x);
        pos.y = Mathf.Round(pos.y);
        transform.position = pos;
        var hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(transform.position, 1);
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftControl)) {
            if (hitColliders.Length == 0) {
                GameObject myGameObject = Instantiate (tilePrefab) as GameObject;
                myGameObject.name = "SomePrefabName";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here we are using Physics.OverlapSphere to detect if we have a collider in the wanted position, and if not in this case, we proceed to continue with the code

Comment: In theory that should work, but it doesn't seem to happen when I do it. I tried changing the values and all I got were more scattered.

Comment: Sorry, i know that you might fixed this already, but the problem might be fixed with changing Input.GetKey to Input.GetKeyUp